# How to make a new serializer class using few fields of two serializers

Tags: django, serialization, model

I have two models, say model1 and model2.
I also have two serializer classes namely ModelOneSerializer and ModelTwoSerializer for both of them.

I would like to create a new serializer class ( with a new model) using few fields from both of the models ( tables).

Now, both of the models have few fields with same name like 'name' , 'capacity' etc. I'd like to use field 'name' from both the models but 'capacity' from the second model.

How can I write this new serializer class using few fields from both of the models?

Answer (score 1):

```
class DispvsLRSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_field_1 = serializers.Charfield(source='fk_1.field', read_only=True)
    fk_field_2 = serializers.Charfield(source='fk_2.field', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
        fields = [.....,
                  .....,
                 'fk_field_1', 
                 'fk_field_2']
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I don't want to create another model, in that case what should we do?  I just want to use those two serializers.

Comment: Main model fields you can directly add to the fields and fk fields as shown above